# Ubuntu 12.04 (Lubuntu), Manage Networks, Panel Icon, Incoming Traffic. Why?

Tags: security

Manage Networks, Panel Icon, it shows constant incoming traffic, not outgoing, just incoming packets, but I am not surfing internet, or doing any updates, I am basically not using internet, so why I got incoming traffic?

Whether is a bad guys intrusion or not, looks like Ubuntu 12.04 (Lubuntu) its blocking it, somehow, but I am not shure.

I thought that there should be no traffic at all, in outgoing and incoming connections, if I am not using internet at all.

How do I stop this traffic?

It something I should be worried about, in terms od security?

Answer (score 0):

There can be various reasons why there may be network traffic even though you're not actively browsing the Internet.

- Depending on your update settings, the update manager might fetch the new package lists automatically but only informs you about available updates, which means that the real, package update process has not been run yet, but the package list update has.
- Some programs submit performance data and crash reports.
- Having an NFS mounted and accessing it might also cause traffic.

You can use [EtherApe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/etherape) to find out where the traffic comes from (run it as root).

If you want to make absolutely sure that there will be no network activity over eth0 (or eth1 or wlan or whatever you are using), you can shut it down using `ifconfig` (you might need root privileges for this):

```
$ ifconfig eth0 down
```

Use `up` instead of `down` to bring it back up.